# Mysql updating multiple textboxes and uploading multiple files at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple html form which has textboxes and file inputs created from a foreach loop. I can upload files with my code but can't update my database. However I can upload the database If I move the query outside the foreach loop but I can't update the file name

```
foreach($_FILES['fileName']['name'] as $key => $value) { 

  $file_name = $_FILES['fileName']['name'][$key];
  $file_size = $_FILES['fileName']['size'][$key];
  $file_tmp = $_FILES['fileName']['tmp_name'][$key];
  $file_ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $uploadLocation = "../upload/".$file_name;

    $move = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$uploadLocation);

    if($move) {


      foreach($_POST['imageID'] as $key => $value) { 
        $image_ID = $_POST['imageID'][$key];
        $image_title = $_POST['imageTitle'][$key];
        $updateImage = $db->execute(
            "UPDATE images
            SET image_title=?, image_name=?
            WHERE ID=$image_ID AND page_id=$page_id",
            array($image_title, $file_name)
        );
      }


      echo "Updated";

    }else{
      echo "Something went wrong!";
    }

}
```

My form :

```
<?php
  // Get images and image titles from the database
  $content_images = $db->get_rows("SELECT * FROM images WHERE page_id = $page_id AND image_type = 'content' ");

    foreach ($content_images as $image) :
      $image_ID = $image->ID;
      $image_name = $image->image_name;
      $image_title = $image->image_title;

?>

<input name="imageTitle[<?php echo $image_ID; ?>]" type="text" value="<?php echo $image_title; ?>">

<img src="<?php echo $upload_folder.$image_name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_title; ?>">

<input type="file" name="fileName[]">
<input type="hidden" name="imageID[<?php echo $image_ID; ?>]" value="<?php echo $image_ID

<?php
  endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you use arrays in your form:

```
...
<input type="file" name="fileName[]">
                                 ^^ zero-based index
<input type="hidden" name="imageID[<?php echo $image_ID; ?>]"
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ID from database index
...
```

Note that you use a zero-based index for the file and for the other form fields you use the ID as the index.

So when you send this information to the server, the index of the file is not related in any way to the index of the text fields.

The solution would be to use the ID everywhere:

```
...
<input type="file" name="fileName[<?php echo $image_ID; ?>]">
<input type="hidden" name="imageID[<?php echo $image_ID; ?>]"
...
```

Now your `$key` variable in php is both the index for the file and for the text fields.

**Edit:** When you do it like that, you need to remove the loop in the loop as now you are overwriting your `$key` / `$value` variables of the outer loop in the inner loop.

You only need one loop and you need to prepare your sql statement before the loop (you are not preparing it at all now). Then in your loop you can use the `$key` variable to execute your statement once with the corresponding `$_POST` variables.

Comment: @Dejavu You also need to update your database code in the loop to not use a loop as now you are overwriting your `$key` / `$value` variables. I will add more information to the question.

Comment: Ok thank you but I couldn't figure out how to write a one loop for both files and textboxes

Comment: @Dejavu If the keys match, that is all you need as you can address both the file and the post variables using the same key.

Comment: I see. You mean that? foreach ($_FILES['fileName']['name'] as $key => $value) { $image_title = $_POST['imageTitle'][$key]; $file_name = $_FILES['fileName']['name'][$key]; }